# Property documentation

Tags: breeze

Are there any entity.property documentation 'field' in breeze?
For example, on an entity.property in EntityFramework are two documentation properties: Long Description and Summary. I can see those two properties in metadata on client side but I am wondering if any of those properties are used in breeze.
Analyzing the breeze.debug.js I didn't notice any usage of those or similar properties but maybe somebody have an idea how to use them (extract from metadata) and attach them for example to an entity instance. Or maybe somebody have some similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good idea!.  Please add this to the breeze [User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/).  We take these suggestions very seriously.  Hopefully we can also get out some documentation describing how to intercept the metadata retrieval process so that you can add your own logic to do this.

As a stopgap, the **MetadataStore.fetchMetadata** method currently **does** return ( in its promise 'then' method) the the raw "metadata" retrieved from the server.  So for now, you could plumb this and pick out these properties and attach them directly to each corresponding breeze dataProperty.

Note that by the time the fetchMetadata method returns the entire MetadataStore will have already been populated with entityTypes, dataProperties, navigationProperties, etc. This makes the task much easier.

Comment: Thanks for info Jay. I will try to use your suggestion and implement it by myself. And for sure I will add this to User Voice as soon as I dig little dipper into the issue.

Comment: No problem and please post about what you discover.

Comment: OK. For now I extracted documentation property from rawMetadata into EntityTypes in the way you suggested. In theory now I could register  EntityTypeConstructor for each entity and extend corresponding Entity object with documentation. However I don't think that this is a good solution.
What I was thinking is to extend each entity 'automatically'. Any suggestion where I could attach my code in order to extend each entity object without any additional action?

Comment: I would suggest that you should extend the entityType since there is only one instance of this for each type.  You can get the entityType easily via the MetadataStore.getEntityType method ( and it is also available as a property on each of your entities).

Comment: True. And this exactly what I have done till now (what actually took couple lines of code). However, I am using knockout.validation and, as you probably know, it extends observables with additional properties. What I was planing to do is to extand properties with documentation info so I could integrate validation with documentation.
Till now I was extending validation and documentation on entityConstructors. But I was wondering maybe there is some place I could do it for all entities (when they are loaded or something).

Comment: The MetadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor (http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html#method_registerEntityTypeCtor) has a third parameter that is an initialization function.  This function will be run on each entity after it has been materialized from the server.  You could perform your logic there.